# Why defined array returns false?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Can someone please explain me why when I do `print_r($student->getStudents())` I get only the size of the array and `is_array` returns false.

This is my output

```
Jane Doe enrolled at Aviation High School
All students:
Nope!3

<?php
 class Student{
 public $name;
 public $students = array('Jason', 'Joe');
 public function __construct($name){
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->students = array_push($this->students, $name);
 }
 public function lastName(){
    return "Doe";
 }

 public function getStudents(){
    return $this->students;
 }
}

class School{
 public $name;
 public function __construct($name){
     $this->name = $name;
 }
}

class Admin{
 public function enroll(Student $student,School $school){
     echo $student->name.' '.$student->lastName().' enrolled at '. $school->name;
     echo '<br />All students:<br />';
     echo is_array($student->getStudents()) ? 'Yeah!':'Nope!' ;
 }
}

$student = new Student("Jane");
$school = new School("Aviation High School");

$admin = new Admin();
$admin->enroll($student, $school);
```

Comment: [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) doesn't work the way you use it I would say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are overwriting the array when you do `array_push` with the length of the array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Change:

```
$this->students = array_push($this->students, $name);
```

To:

```
array_push($this->students, $name);
```

Alternatively just do:

```
$this->students[] = $name;
```

Comment: Haha, beat you by 4 seconds :p Have a +1 on me!

Comment: You're right. Even though I've used `array_push` function numerous times sometimes you overlook little things.

Answer (score 4):

`array_push` does not return a new array, it directly modifies the array you pass it and returns the new length of the array.

Therefore, after calling `$this->students = array_push($this->students,$name)` you have `3` as the value, which is obviously not an array.

[Documentation](http://php.net/array-push)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting students = to array_push, which returns an int. Array push takes an array by reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php